# A smooth window resize animation in WPF using XAML

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I want to resize a window with XAML, but it either resizes the width or the height while I want them both to animate together, I'm using story boards and summoning them from C# in a keydown even

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please include a minimal example of your attempt. Sweet assassins creed profile pic by the way... :)

Comment: How about this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1769317/animate-window-resize-width-and-height-c-sharp-wpf

Comment: I've read many posts, all of them either consider using codes I'm C#, or offer speech without examples. I've tried XAML storyboard, but the width animates first then the height

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help. Anyways, I found the solution, by using "fit to content" property on the window, and making the grid resize instead of the window. That'll make some numbers of width and height differences between the grid and the window, but it'll work